# Display list of elements as table with CSS only?

Tags: css, flexbox

Display list as a table with 3 columns, with the items evenly spread, and having `10px` margin from every sides and between rows.

```
.item { width: 10px; height: 10px; background: black; }
.grid { background: #eee; }

<div class="grid">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Should be rendered as

[image]

It is possible to achieve that with `flex` layout, but it would require more complicated HTML, see example below.

```css
.item { width: 10px; height: 10px; background: black; }

.grid { background: #eee; padding: 10px 10px 0 10px; }
.row { display: flex; justify-content: space-between; padding: 0 0 10px 0;  }
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

I wonder if it would be possible to do with pure CSS, without adding any additional HTML elements. The size of `.items` shouldn't be changed, and it's unknown.

Comment: You have strong constraints. Either you modify DOM as given in your example or modify width of items. But you are not allowing both of these.

Comment: Also, this is usually done using a grid library like bootstrap. But they also play on width property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with flexbox by adding a hidden element between the first and last row that will be `width:100%` thus you will avoid changing the html:

```css
.item {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: black;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #eee;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
}

.row :nth-child(n + 4) {
  order: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

If the number of element is unknown you can consider CSS grid:

```css
.item {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: black;
}
.row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3,1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  padding:10px;
  background: #eee;
}
.row :nth-child(3n + 2) {
  margin:auto;
}
.row :nth-child(3n + 3) {
  margin-left:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Technically, rather than adding an element, OP *could* (theoretically) use [`row-gap`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-align-3/#propdef-row-gap) in the flex container. Though this is relatively new addition to the "box assignment" spec (the link above is a link to the definition of `row-gap` in that spec).

Comment: The `after` element not only creates a row gap, but it also is the 4th element in flex order with 100% width to push the other 3 boxes below on a different flex line. `row-gap` would not push the last 3 boxes on a new row and  hence would have no effect at all.

Comment: @DavidThomas as siddhesh said, my intention wasn't the gap but to create the second row and while doing this I found it easy to use it for the gap instead of margin that I have to remove from some elements.

Answer (score 2):

[Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif) has written a good answer. The flexbox one will work only for 2 to 3 rows but the grid version will work for more items.

The grid CSS can be simplified further by using `space-between`, thus getting rid of margins and `n-th child` selectors.

```css
.item {
   width: 10px;
   height: 10px;
   background: black;
}
   
.row {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: repeat(3,10px); /*change this*/
   grid-gap: 10px;
   padding:10px;
   background: #eee;
   justify-content: space-between;  /*add this*/
 }
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but as far as I understand, with this line - `grid-template-columns: repeat(3,10px)` you explicitly setting column width as `10px` it won't work if you try it with the `.item` of different size.

Comment: You could replace the 10px with `auto`